# How to be notified of Android GC events?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to get notified when Android GC occured or finished each time, especially Compacting GC, but I cannot find out a solution how to get this to work.

As of now I cannot find any documentation about this.

Comment: I am not aware that there is an API for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any API to do so. All you can is to force GC by calling `System.gc();`